# Copy/Paste OneNote 2010 Data

Tags: c#, clipboard, copy-paste, onenote

I'm trying to create a Server/Client application for sending Clipboard data to and from all connected clients (particularly OneNote 2010 Clipboard data) I am trying to copy drawings (with text boxes) out of OneNote into an IDataObject, and then back into OneNote. The only problem is that when I copy the data back onto the clipboard and paste it. The Text has been lost and I only have the drawing. How can I preserve the clipboard data to be as though it never left OneNote?

```
    private void sendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clipboard = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
        //SendData(clipboard);
        for(int i = 0; i< clipboard.GetFormats(true).Length;i++)
        {
            chatHist.Text += clipboard.GetFormats(true)[i] + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }

    private void getButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Clipboard.SetDataObject(clipboard,true);
    }
```

Comment: *Bump*
Formats Returned:
OneNote 2010 Internal
Ink Serialized Format
HTML Format
System.String
UnicodeText
Text
EnhancedMetafile
DeviceIndependentBitmap
 
Image:
http://i50.tinypic.com/255m0it.jpg

Answer (score -1):

You should place multiple data formats on the clipboard for this. This can be done using the [DataObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dataobject.aspx) class.

Comment: This is using a DataObject. clipboard is a DataObject

Comment: This still doesn't solve the issue. Does anyone have any other recommendations?